# sass file is not loading in angular component

Tags: angular

i have designed common print functionality in angular 2 . i wrote a code  like following.

```js
this.printconent = document.getElementById("eq-result-print").innerHTML;
      if (window) {
            if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {

                var popup = window.open('', '_blank',
                    'width=600,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,'
                    + 'location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');

                popup.window.focus();

                popup.document.write('<html><head>  ' +
                    '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen,print"/>' +
                     '<link type="text/x-sass" rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles.scss" media="screen,print"/>' +


                    + '</head><body onload="window.print()"><div class="reward-body">'
                    + this.printconent + '</div></html>');
                popup.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
                    popup.close();
                    return '.\n';
                };
                popup.onabort = function (event) {
                    popup.document.close();
                    popup.close();
                }
            } else {
                var popup = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,menubar=no,toolbar=no,'
                    + 'location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
                popup.document.open();
                popup.document.write('<html><head>' +
                    '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all"/>' +
                  '<link type="text/x-sass"  href="../../styles.scss" />' +

                    + '</head><body onload="window.print()">' + this.printconent + '</html>');
                popup.document.close();
            }

            popup.document.close();

}
```

here i am loading .scss file in link tag. but not loading this file in component . please correct me. where i did wrong. and also i have tried to load by using  styleUrls:['../../sass/styles.scss'] in @Component decorator but this time i am getting "TypeError: cssText.replace is not a function".. so how to load scss file in  component in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

First you add your scss files to the assets folder it is good practice to add a styles folder.

then make sure in your angular-cli file your styleExt property is set to scss if you change this you need to stop the server and restart it again.

Then you can use your scss files in your components scss or the general scss files by adding the import on top

example if you created the styles folder:

```
@import "~assets/styles/_variables.scss";
```

or:

```
@import "~assets/_myscssfile.scss";
```